# Allowing instances of a particular class to be created by only one other class in Java?

Tags: java, singleton, access-modifiers

Suppose that I have two classes A and B and I want to make it so that instances of B can only be created in A and in B itself. I don't want any other class (including subclasses of A) to be allowed to create instances of B. Is there any way of doing this in Java?

Here is a bit of code if it's not clear what I am trying to do:

```
public class A {
    B instance;
    public A(){
        // Still allows for subclasses to access B
        instance = B.getInstance((Object)this);
    }
}
```

Here is the class whose construction I want to limit:

```
public class B {

    // If I make this public all classes can create it, but
    // if I make it private without any getter methods then
    // no other classes but itself can create it
    private B(){}

    // Problem with this is that subclasses of  A
    // can also create instances of B
    public static B getInstance(Object o){
        if(o instanceof A)
            return new B();
        else
            return null;
    } 
}
```

I have tried Googling and searching on StackOverflow for possible solutions, but the closest thing that I have found is using a Singleton design pattern with a modified getInstance() method to make sure only a class with a particular type can have access to instances of class B. While this works fairly well, it still enables any subclass which extends A to get instances of B. Is there any way to stop this from occurring or would it ruin the whole point of subclassing if a subclass couldn't do what its superclass could do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Suppose that I have two classes A and B and I want to make it so that instances of B can only be created in A and in B itself. I don't want any other class (including subclasses of A) to be allowed to create instances of B.

You could make B a private inner class of the A class.

Comment: Is it possible that class not to be inner, but on the same package as his master, but still creatable like a inner class?

Answer (score 1):

> While this works fairly well, it still enables any subclass which
>   extends A to get instances of B. Is there any way to stop this from
>   occurring or would it ruin the whole point of subclassing if a
>   subclass couldn't do what its superclass could do?

If you don't want your class A to be subclassed, you can make class A final, or can have a private constructor for A. Although as suggested in previous answers,, its better to create private inner classes.

```
public final class A {
    B instance;
    public A(){
        // Still allows for subclasses to access B
        instance = B.getInstance((Object)this);
    }
}
```

Comment: While the other answer is slightly better, for my particular application I actually didn't need subclasses of A to be created in the first place so this was useful. Plus it might help if I want to move a lengthy private inner class into its own separate source file for readability purposes. Therefore +1.

Answer (score 1):

`A` can present something to `B` that only `A` can possess. For example

```
public class A
{
    public static class Pass
    {
        private Pass(){}
```

Only `A` can create an `A.Pass` object. If such objects are only transmitted from `A` to `B`, nobody else can get a hold of them and pretend to be `A`.

```
public class B
{
    public static B getInstance(A.Pass token)
    {
        if(pass==null) 
            throw ...      
        else
            caller must be A
```

Answer (score 0):

This class will throw an exception if creating class is not B

```
class A {

    A() {
        new SecurityManager() {
            {
                if (getClassContext()[1] != B.class) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
            }
        };
    }
...
```

you cannot break it even with reflection

Comment: This works albeit I think the condition would have to be getClassContext()[2] != B.class because getClassContext()[1] gives you A.class and getClassContext()[0] gives you the SecurityManager class.